# How to correctly escape an echo

Tags: php, plugin-development, security, escaping

In WordPress they recommend that I should escape any part of the code of my plugin that shows data to the user, I have made most of the corrections but this specific case I don't know how to escape that echo. Please help.

```
<option value="">
    <?php _e( '- Default', MF_TEXT_DOMAIN ); ?>
</option>
<?php foreach ( $folders as $folder ) {
    $folder = trim( $folder );
    echo "<option value=\"{$folder}\">{$folder}</option>";
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Escaping is only necessary when you have no full control of the the thing you are echoing. So as long as `$folder` is a variable that you have defined yourself, there's no real need to escape. But if there is user input involved, there is [`esc_html`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html/), to be used as follows:

```
echo esc_html ("this input string contains a > character");
```

In this case, however, more drastic measures may be needed, because there can be no html tags at all inside `option` tags, so you add [`wp_strip_all_tags`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_strip_all_tags/) like this:

```
$folder = wp_strip_all_tags ($folder);
echo esc_html ("<option value=\"{$folder}\">{$folder}</option>");
```

UPDATE (thanks to Kero in the comments for noticing the error)

```
$folder = esc_html (wp_strip_all_tags ($folder));
echo "<option value=\"{$folder}\">{$folder}</option>";
```

Comment: Won't this return `&lt;option value...` which is invalid HTML?

Comment: I understand, but WordPress requires me to always escape for security. In this case, any escape attempt that I make in that echo results in nothing being shown in the output, it does not return the value of $folder, it does not show anything. Even your answer I just tried. I don't know if I should add that this <option> is part of a <select> and that $folders comes from the database with a get_option()
But without escape, as it is in my question, it works correctly